# How to define the node entering position in D3 js force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to implement a radial force layout in D3.js , I saw a similar example but i am stuck on how to initiate the node positions in the layout.

http://bl.ocks.org/vlandham/5087480

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What you have done upto now?

Answer (score 0):

Initialising a position is just done by setting the cx and cy positions. The most logical place is where the radius is currently being set i.e.

```
.attr("r", 10)
.attr("cx", 5) //added
.attr("cy", 5) //added
```

Of course, you can do something more exotic if you are using the bound data to initialise position.

This will only set the starting point though - the force layout will then take over and position elements. The advantage is that you can potentially reduce some of the initial node movement if you get it right.